# Vw и Vh или @media

Tags: вёрстка

Здравствуйте!

У меня с другом возник спор: что лучше *vw и vh* или *@media-запросы*?

Я утверждаю, что *vw и vh* можно и нужно внедрять в разработку сайтом потому, что эти величины помогают подстраивать сайту под любые разрешения экранов. По-этому я решил создать мини-сайт где эти величины будут везде

```css
div {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vh;
  font-size: 5vw;
  background-color: black;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div>
  DiV
</div>
```

Они маштабируют блоки под все разрешение экранов, при этом сохраняя нормально расположение блоков (как на больших экранах, так и на маленьких). А `@media` не удобен тем, что там вручную нужно указывать все размеры, которые должны быть не устройствах. Ведь всё равно, никогда не знаешь с какого устройства зайдёт пользователь.

Мой же друг утверждает, что `@media` лучше, т.к. техника довольно стойкая, используется на многих сайтах и устройствах и он отлично справляется со своей обязанностью подстраиванием. А `vw и vh` бесполезная вещь, которая в принципе и не нужна во все. Зачем они, если подстраивать можно с помощью `@media`?

**Так что же лучше использовать *vw и vh* или `@media` в подстройке сайта под разные экраны?**

Comment: И того и другого! И можно без хлеба (с) Пух

Comment: @vp_arth, увы. Зачем media если применяется viewport или зачем viewport если применяется media?

Comment: Вот вы изменили ширину окна браузера, 5 колонок(20vw) перестали влезать. Что дальше?

Comment: @vp_arth, не перестали.  20vw - это 20% от размера окна браузера и блоки с ужаться или расширяться. Смотря куда изменишь

Comment: К телефону лупа прилагается? Медиа-запросы хороши тем, что позволяют показывать **разную** верстку на разных layout.

Comment: @vp_arth, лупу? А зачем тогда мобильные версии сайта? Если у тебя указана мобильная версия <400px, а ширина нового айфона 800px?

Comment: Я думаю мою точку зрения вы поняли, но не приняли. Это не место для холиваров, а для чата времени не особо.

Comment: @vp_arth, будет время, напишите мнение в ответе :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это совершенно разные вещи, использование которых друг другу никак не противоречит. Задание размеров чего бы то ни было в единицах `vw`/`vh` и `@media`-запросы имеют совершенно разные предназначения.

Используйте `vw`/`vh`, когда вам нужно единицы измерения относительно ширины/высоты экрана.

Используйте `@media`, когда вам нужно разные стили под разные разрешения, под разные устройства, стили чисто для печати и т.д.

Comment: Минусаторы, а прокомментировать?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ни о какой точности идти речь не может тогда. 1vw - 1% от ширины окна. Чтобы сверстать 120 пикселей блок, тебе нужно указать 1.2vw, но в голове постоянно держать суть того, что ты верстаешь от 100px ширины. Это лишний гемор.
Но это ещё совсем не беда)
Беда начнется там, когда нужно будет изменять стили.
Я тебя удивлю, но: для мобилок нужно не нормальное отображение сайта (это в том числе, но не только), а ещё и дизайн соответствующий. И без медиазапроса ИЗМЕНИТЬ дизайн можно только через костыли, которые будут работать через пень-колоду (в лучшем случае), а в худшем - будут сложнее, чем ненавистный тобой @media.
А то, что будут проблемы со скейлингом и что браузеру заново нужно будет пересчитывать ширину всего на странице - это не обсуждается даже. Браузер выводит пиксели, а не % ширины. Это нужно считать и отрисовывать.

Когда тебе придет макет в фотошопе и сказано будет "сделай так", то ничего у тебя не получится.
Потому что ширина макета будет каких-нибудь 2140 пикселей, и ты будешь бегать с калькулятором всё пересчитывать?

Comment: `vw/vh/vm` - таки имеют место быть иногда. Когда вам действительно нужна треть экрана, а не 713px от вышеуказанного макета.

Comment: @Anon, я не сказал, что от вьюпорт-величин следует отказаться навсегда. А применять тогда, как ты сказал - когда нужны проценты от ширины экрана. Эти величины не призваны делать респонсибл-дизайн.

Comment: Хотел поставить плюс, но передумал, когда понял, что ответ сводится к "всегда и везде используйте пиксели". Принципиально не согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я тоже не согласен! Посмотри в коммент выше-то. Я тоже vh и vw использую. Типичный пример: модальное окно.

Comment: @VostokSisters, модальное окно можно сделать и без них.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну так чё угодно можно сделать без них, но с js  =_= Это пример, где можно их обоснованно использовать.

Comment: @VostokSisters, у меня диалог получается и без них, и без js.

Comment: @Qwertiy, просто докопаться решил, я понял.

Answer (score 0):

грамотный подход  я к примеру делаю браузерную игру стратегию  дает при помощи vw и так д..  отличный результат , минус один для мобильников нет масштабируемости .. там уже идет просто в моем случае второй стиль который выбирает пользователь . но не забываем что многие игроманы уже сидят на мониторах минимум 20 дюймов  и больше при 4 к мониторах  это я сжц по своим пользователям  вот тут параметры новые отрабатывают на ура подгоняюсь под размеры экрана  просто правильно используйте вложенность блоков  и не будет не чего вылазить плюс есть не большой скриптик который  даже при px  дает эффект тоже самого что и vw and vh

Comment: это ответ или просто поток сознания?